# Excel 2013 - Vlookup Errors

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a file with 4000+ rows of data.  When doing Vlookup, some of the rows worked yet some didn't. It is the same formula that was applied across the rows.  Tested with storing data in both tabs as text and as values, and with both, some rows worked, some don't.  Along the way, I have a tab stored as text (value with apostrophe mark) and one as value.  Would appreciate guidance on what could have went wrong? Any better way to do search value in excel to disregard whether the data is stored as text or value?

Screenshots of the tables:
[image]
To return results under Location.  Applied formula shown in column D
[image]
Data file

Comment: Try to check if data in Column A in 2 Worksheets are having the same cell format: number

Comment: Still get the same error after confirming it is the same cell format.

Comment: Try to provide the problem file here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your formula with

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(A2),Ref!$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.Some field apparently worked, some didn't. After testing, I think the only way is to rework my data file.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Jen I think the best possible solution is to set datatype in 2nd table to text.